# Bison: Bad if structure

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I've made a complete parser in bison ( and of course complete lexer in flex ), and I noticed only yesterday that I've a problem in my parser. In If structure in fact.

Here are my rules in my parser: http://pastebin.com/TneESwUx

Here the single IF is not recognized, and if I replace "%prec IFX" with "END", by adding a new token "END" (`"end" return END;` in flex), it works. But I don't want to have a new "end" keyword, that's why I don't use this solution.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar is ambiguous, so you have to live with the shift/reduce conflict. The `END` token eliminates the ambiguity by ensuring that an `IF` statement is always properly closed, like a pair of parentheses.

Parentheses make a good analogy here. Suppose you had a grammar like this:

```
maybe_closed_parens : '(' stuff
                    | '(' stuff ')'
                    ;
```

`stuff` itself generates some grammar symbols, and one of them is `maybe_closed_parens`.

So if you have input like `((((((whatever`, it is correct. The parentheses do not have to be closed. But what if you add `)`? Which `(` is it closing?

This is very much like not being able to tell which `IF` matches an `ELSE`.

If you add `END` to the syntax of the `IF` (whether or not there is an `ELSE`), then that is like having a closing parentheses. `IF` and `END` are like `(` and `)`.

Of course, you are stylistically right not to want the word `END` in your language, because you already have curly braced blocks, which are basically an alternate spelling for Pascal's `BEGIN` and `END`. Your `}` is already an `END` keyword.

So what you can do is impose the rule that an `IF` accepts only compound statements (i.e. fully braced):

```
if_statement : IF condition compound_statement
             | IF condition compound_statement ELSE compound_statement
```

Now it is impossible to have an ambiguity like if x if y w else z because braces must be present: `if x { if y { w } else { z } } or if x { if y { w } } else { z }`.

I seem to recall that Perl is an example of a language which has made this choice. It's not a bad idea because not only does it eliminate your ambiguity, more importantly it eliminates ambiguities from programs.

I see that you don't have a `compound_statement` phrase structure rule in your grammar because your statement generates a phrase enclosed in `{` and `}` directly. You will have to hack that in if you take this approach.

Comment: So, your solution is to always force braces? And if I don't want that? If I want my if/else statement like in C?

Comment: If you want the if/else statement like in C, then you keep the ambiguous grammar with the shift/reduce conflict. Yacc resolves it by choosing the shift action over reduce, and so the parser will match the `else` with the closest `if`. The `%expect` declaration can be used to indicate that a certain number of conflicts are expected from the grammar.

Comment: Okay, you haven't understand my problem... If I use the ambiguous grammar, Bison don't recognize a simple `IF` statement. ( without `else` )

Comment: In that code for example: http://pastebin.com/WVHj6v2S Bison will not recognize the end of the first if. But if I add else { dootherthing; } it's okay...

Comment: What happens if you have if without else? Syntax error? (Also, I don't see terminating semicolons on your rules).

Comment: No, not syntax error, but as I said, Bison don't recognize the end of the first if. My complete parser file is here: https://raw.github.com/Quent42340/Eplith/master/EPlib/source/parser.y

Comment: Ok, the problem was from another part of my code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

'The correct way to handle this kind of rule is not precedence, it is refactoring to use an optional else-part so that the parser can use token lookahead to decide how to parse.  I would design it something like this:

```
stmt      : IF '(' expression ')' stmts else_part
          | /* other statement productions here */

else_part : /* optional */
          | ELSE stmts

stmts     : stmt
          | '{' stmt_list '}'
          | '{' '}'

stmt_list : stmt
          | stmt_list ';' stmt
```

(This method of special-casing `stmts` instead of allowing `stmt` to include a block may not be optimal in terms of productions, and may introduce oddities in your language, but without more details it's hard to say for certain.  `bison` can produce a report showing you how the parser it generated works; you may want to study it.  Also beware of unexpected shift/reduce conflicts and especially of any reduce/reduce conflicts.)

Note that shift/reduce conflicts are entirely normal in this kind of grammar; the point of an LALR(1) parser is to use these conflicts as a feature, looking ahead by a single token to resolve the conflict.  They are reported specifically so that you can more easily detect the ones you *don't* want, that you introduce by incorrectly factoring your grammar.

Your `IfExpression` also needs to be refactored to match; the trick is that `else_part` should produce a conditional expression of some kind to `$$`, and in the production for `IF` you test `$6` (corresponding to `else_part`) and invoke the appropriate `IfExpression` constructor.

Comment: Here is my real stmts rule: 

    `stmts:
     stmt | '{' stmt_list '}' | '{' '}' ;`
I want to keep this rule like that. So what is the solution for optional else here?

Comment: Your `stmt_list` is my `stmts`; then use your `stmts` where I used `stmt in productions.  I'll edit to match.

Comment: And my real stmt rule is like that: `stmt: IF '(' exp ')' stmts %prec IFX { $$ = new IfExpression($3, $5); }
 | IF '(' exp ')' stmts ELSE stmts { $$ = new IfExpression($3, $5, $7); }` So one rule with one different action. With your solution it isn't possible, right?

Comment: I didn't replicate your `stmts` properly before; should be correct now.  Hopefully I explained the other one usefully; the point is that the kind of if/else you want *is* necessarily ambiguous, and some kind of lookahead is necessary to resolve it.  This ambiguity is reported as a shift/reduce conflict.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want a shift/reduce conflict. The precedence solution is recommended in John Levine's book..

Comment: Precedence is another way to phrase the exact same thing I'm doing here (it is still a shift/reduce conflict; your grammar *is* ambiguous, you cannot escape this).  It's not a way intended for this use case, and you need to twist the grammar to make it fit.  When `bison` lets you write things more clearly, it's silly to abuse precedence that way.  Unless by referencing that book, your point is that you're trying to learn parser theory; in which case, (a) you should have stated that up front and (b) you're going to learn that it's the painful solution.

Comment: I told you how in the most recent update; see the last paragraph.

Comment: So the shift/reduce conflict is inevitable?

Comment: One way or another, yes.  The grammar you want is ambiguous; I encourage you to think about why this is true, and why using an "end" rule is not ambiguous.

Comment: It doesn't work with your rule... I've a new shift/reduce conflict, but the simple if statement is not recognized.

Comment: The discussion is right, but the answer is wrong. Refactoring the grammar like this does not enable the parser to use lookahead. The lookahead by one token is always there, period. Refactoring the grammar can sometimes help the parser generator sort out conflicts in what to do in certain states with certain lookahead.  No amount of refactoring will eliminate a true ambiguity, like which of several `if`-s takes the `else`.